# Inverse limit of a quotient space (simple question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, limits-colimits

**Setup:**

I have a tower of abelian groups $\hspace{1em} \cdots \to A_3 \stackrel{f_2}{\to} A_2 \stackrel{f_1}{\to} A_1 \stackrel{f_0}{\to} A_0$.

There are similar towers for $B_i, C_i$, and $D_i$.

There is also an exact sequence $0 \to A_i \xrightarrow{\alpha} B_i \to C_i \to D_i \to 0$.

From this sequence, we derive the short sequence $0 \to \text{coker} \alpha \to C_i \to D_i \to 0$ where $\text{coker} \alpha = B_i/\text{im} \alpha$.

It is known that $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i A_i = 0$ and that $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i B_i = 0$.

**Question:**

Does it follow that $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i (B_i/\text{im} \alpha) = 0$?

**Thoughts:**

I proved that $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i A_i = 0$ directly from the definition of the inverse limit and that $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i B_i = 0$ by showing that the map $\partial$ is injective in the sequence

$$0 \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_n B_n \longrightarrow \underset{n}{\prod} B_n \stackrel{\partial}{\longrightarrow} \underset{n}{\prod} B_n \longrightarrow \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}^1_n B_n \to 0.$$

Using the second method again, if $\partial$ is injective, then a restriction of the $\partial$ map to $\underset{n}{\prod} B_n/(\text{im} \alpha)$ will also be injective.

This is why I think that $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i (B_i/\text{im} \alpha) = 0$. Is this incorrect?

*Aside*

Obviously I renamed the groups since the original ones are cohomology groups and would take forever to write. I tried to include everything that is necessary for this specific question, but I will edit if I see I'm missing an important detail.

Thank you for your time even reading this!

Comment: I personally doubt this, it seems you want $\varprojlim\,^1$ conditions on $\ker\alpha$ and stuff like that

Comment: @FShrike Thank you!! I will work on that.

Comment: Hi @FShrike, I calculated that im$\alpha$ is $R^n$ for some $n$ and ring $R$. (Or im$\alpha$ could be trivial, but then the result is obvious.) Does that mean $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}_i (B_i/R^n) = 0$? 

Comment: $\mathrm{im}\,\alpha$ is *always* $R^n$? For all $i$? Then yes. It is probably best if you show us exactly what the towers are, that you're dealing with (since you seem to have a specific example in mind)

Comment: @FShrike Thank you!! I didn't write out the towers because they are more complicated than the inverse limit question alone, and I really just wanted to know when the inverse limit of a quotient is trivial when the original is trivial.

Comment: @FShrike The towers are $A_i = H^1(V_i/ (V_i - K_{i,n}))$, $B_i = H^1(V_i \cap U_i / (V_i - (K_{i,n}) \cap L_{i,n}))$, $C_i = H^2(V_i \cup U_i/ (V_i \cup U_i - (K_{i,n} \cup L_{i,n}))) $, and $D_i = H^2(V_i/ (V_i - K_{i,n})) $. All of those form a Mayer Vietories sequence. A different question I had about that sequence is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840070/explanation-of-these-mayer-vietoris-maps. Unfortunately I chose A, B, C, D to mean completely different things in that question than they mean in the question here.

Comment: @FShrike But I realized that $B_i$ and im$\alpha$ might be homotopy equivalent to first cohomologies of wedges of circles, which is why im$\alpha$ might just be $R_n$.

Comment: Let me clarify my comment. If $\mathrm{im}\,\alpha$ is always $R^n$ *for the same ring $R$ and the same exponent $n$* i.e. the tower $\mathrm{im}\,\alpha$ is constant, then it follows $\varprojlim\mathrm{coker}\alpha=0$ as desired (essentially because the trivial Mittag Leffer condition is satisfied). I don't think that's the case here, though. It would help to add extra supporting information to the main post itself, to avoid the "XY problem" issue